# github actions: SSH into droplet and run code

Tags: ssh, github-actions, digital-ocean

I want to deploy a github project automatically through github actions when I push my code to github. My yaml-file looks like this:

```
name: push-and-deploy-to-server

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          port: 22
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          source: "."
          target: "."
      - uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          port: 22
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            npm install
            pm2 restart index.js
```

I have a server with an SSH keypair. The public key is added to the server authorized_keys, and I can SSH through my terminal to the server.

When I push code to the github repo, the action runs. I get the following error:

> drone-scp error:  ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain

The weird thing is: after this error, I'm not able to SSH into my server anymore, even through my console I get a "Permission denied (publickey)". So before running the github action, everything works, after that it fails.

The ip address of the server is SSH_HOST, the username which I use to SSH into the server is set in SSH_USERNAME and the private key (the same as I use on my local laptop to ssh into the server) is set in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY.

Does anyone have encountered the same problem before? I have really no clue whats going on here.

**Edit:** extra information: it's a **private** repository.

Comment: i am working on similar setup, will update if i find a workaround, @sam-leurs if you have resolved this please update with an answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a super late answer but i was running into the same problem with trying to deploy something onto a droplot. I created an ssh key and was getting the `ssh handshake failed` issue also the thing that I had to do was add the public key to my authorized key list:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```